# Как пишется "никому не подобен"?

Tags: орфография

Увидел в интернете слоган: "никому не обязан, ни к чему не привязан, ни кому не подобен, потому и свободен". Вопрос: неужели "никому" может писаться раздельно в данном случае?

Answer (score 3):

Нет никаких причин для раздельного написания отрицательного местоимения НИКОМУ, это обычная усилительная конструкция: никому не обязан, никому не подобен.

Answer (score 0):

Подобные местоимения пишутся или одним словом, или в три слова (если появляется предлог: ни с кем, ни у кого)